# Understanding "Mastering Out" in Graduate Programs: Implications and Consequences

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, career-path, academic-life

One of my friends have been currently navigating through graduate studies and have come across the term "mastering out." My questions are that:

1. What does "mastering out" of a graduate program typically entail? Is it considered a voluntary decision or is it often suggested by the program advisors/faculty?
2. What are the common reasons students might choose to or be advised to master out?
3. How is mastering out perceived in academia and in the professional world? Does it carry any negative connotations, or is it viewed as a practical decision under certain circumstances?
4. Are there any long-term consequences of mastering out on a student's academic and professional opportunities?

Comment: Is there a particular country you're interested in? While the very big picture is similar in most places (you leave a program early with an exit award of a Masters degree "by research" rather than a PhD) the precise details and timelines will vary by country (and institution & field) like a lot of academia.

Comment: In the U.S., and in subjects that I'm familiar with (math, physics, philosophy, history), this usually occurs when a student realizes the rigor of a Ph.D. program is more than they wish to deal with or more than they can handle -- voluntary -- OR when a student does not pass the Ph.D. exams (within the required time and/or within the required number of attempts, which varies with the university) -- not voluntary. As for #3 and #4, it's often the case that no one would know whether you did this as opposed to simply entering the graduate program with the intention of only getting a Masters.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I'd say there can be a lot of causes besides too much rigor, including life changes (birth of a child; a spouse needing to relocate for a job) that are not well supported by academia, personal conflicts with a supervisor, loss of funding, recognition that a tenure track/academic career is unlikely based on progress so far, etc.

Comment: Recommend reopening this question. While we normally discourage multiple questions in one post, I think it makes sense in this case since all four are closely related and serve only to more fully qualify the title question.

Comment: @Bryan Krause: I completely agree with your additional reasons. However, I had only 4 or 5 characters available when I finished, so I couldn't expand anymore on what I wrote (without using more than one comment, which I decided then not to do). My "usually occurs" is based on my experience in several U.S. math graduate programs and many people I knew in other programs. Also, at least in the U.S., I'm not sure how anyone later (e.g. an employer) would know whether you initially tried to get a Ph.D. or you only sought a Masters degree to begin with unless you told them, **(continued)**

Comment: although of course you might have to tell them in the case that you failed your Ph.D. exams when applying to another program, since the failure might be part of your formal academic record from that university, which an official transcript would show (besides, this is certainly something you would be expected to tell the admissions committee for another program even if it is not mentioned on your official transcript, although I don't see why you would need to tell an employer). However, I'm sure things are different in other parts of the world, and possibly even in other fields in the U.S.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Perhaps that's more common in math, then, doesn't match my experience though. As far as employers, it's probably not as big of a deal if you're done in 2-3 years, but if you're deeper into a PhD it'll be harder to explain that 'gap' in your record where you were a masters student without an apparent job, when your actual job was being a PhD student. I wouldn't write "FAILED PHD" anywhere on a job application but someone savvy will figure it out; I don't think it's that important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mastering Out means that someone leaves a doctoral program prematurely and is awarded/earned a masters degree instead. It means that the doctoral program can't continue at that institution, though the person might be able to join another one, probably at a different university.

It can be voluntary, as when a person has family or health issues that prevent their continuation. But it might mean, and often does, that the parson has failed some important (comprehensive/qualifying) examinations and are so no longer eligible for a doctorate.

The consequences for an academic career depend on whether the person can be accepted to another doctoral program and complete it successfully. I have evidence that this can happen, even with a change to a higher rated university. But if there is no further degree, the person is probably closed from much of academia.

The perception of the individual can vary. Some at the original institution probably have a negative impression, others may not and might even help in a transition (again, I have evidence of such happening). But the long term reputation depends on what the person is later able to accomplish. It is a stumble, perhaps, but not necessarily a fatal one.

Some people change career plans after this happens. Others just resolve to continue and may succeed in their quest or not. Every case is individual.

Answer (score 1):

Students decide to "master our" when they leave a program before they finish. The option to leave the program may be voluntary or not, but you're not forced to get a masters degree. A student should master out if possible when they plan to quit the PhD because they just don't want to do it anymore or because they're failing.

Mastering out is mostly "leaving academia". To someone in industry, you become a person with a masters degree. Generally that's a better thing than not having a masters degree. It may even be a better thing than having a PhD to some people hiring.

I would ordinarily consider mastering out to be effectively *leaving academia*. That's fine, most everyone leaves academia, there's too few long term career spots for everyone to remain. There is some slim chance to return (lots of Q&A here about that), but generally I'd recommend making a clean break and figuring out what non-academic career to do after mastering out.